# Unable to throw my custom exception

Tags: java

I'm trying to analyze a list of albums from a file.There are 22 albums in my list and one of the items in the list is a duplicate and another is not in correct form.I'm supposed to throw two exceptions and print helpful messages on the console.My InputMismatchException is working fine, although my program should continue reading file inputs skipping the album object/line in the list where the exception occurred.Another exception is a DuplicateAlbumException, which is a custom exception.This exception should ignore the duplicate, print a helpful message on the console that mentions that the duplicate has been ignored , and only read the item one time. The following is my txt file that has inputs of albums:`top20albums.txt`

```
Led Zeppelin    IV  1971
Led Zeppelin    II  1969
Fleetwood Mac   Rumors  1977
Pink Floyd  The Wall    1979
XXXXX   XXXXXXXXX   XXXX
The Clash   London Calling  1979
The Beatles Abbey Road  1969
Van Morrison    Moondance   1971
Talking Heads   Fear of Music   1979
Who Who's Next  1971
The Beatles Rubber Soul 1965
Cure    Kiss Me, Kiss Me, Kiss Me   1987
Violent Femmes  Violent Femmes  1982
Pink Floyd  The Wall    1979
Soul Coughing   Ruby Vroom  1994
James   Laid    1993
Liz Phair   Exile in Guyville   1993
Pink Floyd  Dark Side of the Moon   1973
Police  Zenyatta Mondatta   1980
Led Zeppelin    Houses of the Holy  1973
Soul Coughing   Irresistable Bliss  1996
Replacements    Tim 1985
```

Expected output:

```
java AlbumList top20albums.txt
ERROR: Line 5: Invalid input for year. Skipping line
ERROR: Line 14: Duplicate album 'The Wall' by Pink Floyd
Album Rankings from top20albums.txt
Rank Title Artist Year
---- ------------------------------ -------------------- ----
1 IV Led Zeppelin 1971
2 II Led Zeppelin 1969
3 Rumors Fleetwood Mac 1977
4 The Wall Pink Floyd 1979
5 London Calling The Clash 1979
6 Abbey Road The Beatles 1969
7 Moondance Van Morrison 1971
8 Fear of Music Talking Heads 1979
9 Who's Next Who 1971
10 Rubber Soul The Beatles 1965
11 Kiss Me, Kiss Me, Kiss Me Cure 1987
12 Violent Femmes Violent Femmes 1982
13 Ruby Vroom Soul Coughing 1994
14 Laid James 1993
15 Exile in Guyville Liz Phair 1993
16 Dark Side of the Moon Pink Floyd 1973
17 Zenyatta Mondatta Police 1980
18 Houses of the Holy Led Zeppelin 1973
19 Irresistible Bliss Soul Coughing 1996
20 Tim Replacements 1985
```

My output on the eclipse console:

```
ERROR: Line 5: Invalid input for year. Skipping line.

Rank Title                  Artist       Year
---- -----                  ------       -----

1    IV                             Led Zeppelin         1971
2    II                             Led Zeppelin         1969
3    Rumors                         Fleetwood Mac        1977
4    The Wall                       Pink Floyd           1979
```

My effort so far is in the following:

class #1

```
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------
/**
*  This Album class has four data fields; String title,String artist,
*  int year, int rank.I will be creating an ArrayList of Album object in   another class later
*  which I will name as AlbumList.This Album class represents each Album o  object in the 
*  top20albums.txt file, where we have 22 albums.
* 
*  @author Anonymous 
*  @version Mar 26, 2016
*/
public class Album
{
private String title;
private String artist;
private int year;
private int rank;
public Album () {

}

public Album(String title,String artist,int year,int rank) {
  //this(title,artist,year);
   this.title = title;
    this.artist = artist;
    this.year = year;
    this.rank = rank;

}
public Album(String title,String artist,int year) {
    this.title=title;
    this.artist=artist;
    this.year=year;
    rank = -1;
 }
public String getTitle()
{
    return title;
}

public  String getArtist()
{
    return artist;
}

public int getYear()
{
    return year;
}

public int getRank()
{
    return rank;
}
public void setRank(int rank)
{
    this.rank = rank;
}
/*
 * // ----------------------------------------------------------
 * overridden boolean method from the Object class which tests if
 * two Album objects have the same artist and title or not.Later based on the 
 * invokation of the method we will throw the custom DuplicateAlbumException
 */

public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if(obj instanceof Album )

    return (this.title.equals(((Album)obj).title)) && (this.artist.equals(((Album)obj).artist));
  else
      return this == obj;
   }

public  String toString() {
    return String.format("%-4d %-30s %-20s %-4d", rank,title,artist,year);
}
}
```

class #2

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------
/**
*  This AlbumList class will create ArrayList of Album objects, read inputs  from the
*  top20Albums.txt file and then analyze the album inputs.It will print  album inputs
*  on the console in neat columns, throw two exceptions; one is expected to  occur at
*  line 5 because of the type mismatch, another is expected to occur at line  15 because of
*  the album duplication.I will later create a custom  DuplicateAlbumException class that 
*  will throw exception when the Scanner reads the duplicate file and print a helpful
*  message on the console. 
* 
*  @author Anonymous
*  @version Mar 26, 2016
*/
public class AlbumList
{

private  List <Album> albums ;
public AlbumList(){
    albums = new ArrayList<>();
}
// ----------------------------------------------------------
/**
 * This method reads file input and throws exceptions robustly.
 * @param inFile
 */
public void ReadAlbumsFromFile(File inFile)   {

    int count = 0;
    int rank = 1;
    try {

       Scanner input = new Scanner(inFile);
       input.useDelimiter("\\t|[\\n\\r\\f]+");

       while (input.hasNext()) {



           String artist = input.next();
           String title = input.next();
           int year = input.nextInt();

       Album albumObject = new Album(title,artist,year,rank);

         addAlbum(albumObject);
          count ++;
          rank++;
        }
     }
// This exception will not occur unless I give it a file input that does not  exist.
    catch (FileNotFoundException exception)
    {
        System.out.println("The file  was not found.");
    }
 /* This exception works fine.However, the Scanner should continue reading  the file
 * inputs just skipping the 5th line where the mismatch occur.My program for some reason
 * is not printing any more input after skipping the line and that is my  problem.
 */

    catch (InputMismatchException exception)
    {
        System.out.println("ERROR: Line "+(count+1)+": Invalid input for  year. Skipping line.");
    }
    catch (DuplicateAlbumException exception)
    {

        System.out.println(exception.getMessage());
        Album object = new Album();
       System.out.println("ERROR: Line "+(count+1)+": Duplicate    album"+object.getTitle()+" by "+object.getArtist());

    }



   }

    // ----------------------------------------------------------
    /**
     * This DuplicateAlbumException should work fine if the Scanner keeps reading
     * even after the mismatch exception occurs, at least that is what it seems
     * to me because we are still unable to read line 15 where we expect the duplicate to occur.
     * The custom duplicate exception class was already made.
     * @param albumObject
     * @throws DuplicateAlbumException
     */
    public void addAlbum (Album albumObject) throws DuplicateAlbumException {

           for(int i =0; i < albums.size();i++) {
            if(albums.get(i).equals(albumObject)) {
     throw new DuplicateAlbumException(albumObject.getTitle(),albumObject.getArtist());
            }
        }      
      /* Look that I am adding albumObjects after the catch blocks so IT  SHOULD
       * continue reading file inputs even after the exception occurs but it is not doing
       * so.
       */

           albums.add(albumObject);


    }
    public void printAlbums () {

        albums.toString();
        for (int i = 0; i < albums.size(); i++ )
            System.out.println(albums.get(i));
        }

    public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception {
       /*This is a way to write on the console so that the user can
        * write the file name on the runtime console. 
        */
        if (args.length != 1) {
            System.out.println("java AlbumList top20albums.txt ");
            System.exit(0);
          }
        AlbumList albumListObject = new AlbumList();
        File currentFile = new File(args[0]);
        albumListObject.ReadAlbumsFromFile(currentFile) ;
        System.out.println("\nRank Title  \t\t\t    Artist \t\t Year");
        System.out.println("---- -----  \t\t\t    ------ \t\t -----\n");
        albumListObject.printAlbums();


    }
   }
```

class #3

```
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------
/**
*  This is my custom exception class.
* 
*  @author Anonymous
*  @version Mar 26, 2016
*/
public class DuplicateAlbumException extends ArrayStoreException 
{
public DuplicateAlbumException(String title,
   String  artist) {
    super ("Duplicate album" + title+
        "by" + artist);

}
}
```

I hope my code blocks have enough information and explanation for you to understand my concern.But i would explicitly say it again: Why my Scanner stopped reading file input after the mismatch exception?

Comment: Way too much code. A question like this should only include relevant, minimal code and the actual errors to help answer the question. Please review the help documentation for more information on how to accomplish this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I'm not totally sure but as far as I know, when a program encounters an error in a try/catch statement it will terminate whatever process it was doing, so most likely it stops reading the file when the exception occurs.

Comment: @pczeus i was told by some high reputation users that my questions don't have enough information that's why I did my best to explain.

Comment: Surround the `addAlbum(...)` call with a `try...catch..` if you don't want the loop to stop when a `DuplicateAlbumException` exception occurs. The same goes for the `InputMismatchException` exception.

Comment: Fair enough. But we don't need all classes, just the on with the exception handling. And you don't need to show all contents of the input, just a small section of each at most. I didn't downvote you, only commented.

Comment: Good choices of music by the way :)

Comment: @pczeus hehe thanks.

Comment: @Titus nope it's not working.

Comment: You are never checking for a duplicate album. You might want to use a Set instead of a List to avoid duplicate albums.  You should check for a duplicate, and then actually throw the duplicate album exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the `.nextInt()` is throwing the `InputMismatchException` causing the control to go out of the `while` loop. Refactor the code to

```
try {

   Scanner input = new Scanner(inFile);
   input.useDelimiter("\\t|[\\n\\r\\f]+");

   while (input.hasNext()) {

    try{
       String artist = input.next();
       String title = input.next();
       int year = input.nextInt();

   Album albumObject = new Album(title,artist,year,rank);

     addAlbum(albumObject);
      count ++;
      rank++;
}
catch (InputMismatchException exception)
{
    System.out.println("ERROR: Line "+(count+1)+": Invalid input for  year. Skipping line.");
}

    }
 }
// This exception will not occur unless I give it a file input that does not  exist.
catch (FileNotFoundException exception)
{
    System.out.println("The file  was not found.");
}
 /* This exception works fine.However, the Scanner should continue reading  the file
 * inputs just skipping the 5th line where the mismatch occur.My program for some reason
 * is not printing any more input after skipping the line and that is my  problem.
 */
```

I hope this solves your problem

Comment: Hi, your solution only reads first 11 lines.It's still not throwing the duplicate exception, i.e. , it stops at line 5 but not reading line 6 and lines after next duplicate.

Comment: Yes, it was an answer to `But i would explicitly say it again: Why my Scanner stopped reading file input after the mismatch exception?` Continuing on the same lines, you can keep bringing in your exception handler inside the while loop for exceptions which you want to continue with.

Comment: Well, you got it then.I would really appreciate further help but thanks :).

Comment: I was able to get it till first 19 lines using the while loop fact that you mentioned.However, it's never printing line 6 immediately after the mismatch exception.Also, it's printing the mismatch exception message three times, instead of just once.

Comment: @Afif the scanner does not advance, so it gets the first missmatch exception, then it advances 2 times and tries to get the next int, but you are only on the next title. Then it advances two times from that, and tries to get the next int, but you are on the artist. Then it advances 2 times and you are back to the year, so it gets the year correctly and you are back on track. But you've thrown out two additional albums.

Answer (score 0):

First of we are going to use a set, because you do not want duplicate albums.

Second we are going to say each line has an album. The reason to do this is because your Scanner will not advance when there is an input missmatch exception. Then you have another problem, where you scanner is not on the next line.

```
Set<Album> albums = new HashSet<>();
try( 
        BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(
            inFile.toPath(), Charset.forName("UTF8")
        )
    ){
    String line;
    while((line = reader.readline())!=null){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(line);
        input.useDelimiter("\\t|[\\n\\r\\f]+");
        int rank = 0;
        try{
            String artist = input.next();
            String title = input.next();
            int year = input.nextInt();
            Album albumObject = new Album(title,artist,year,rank);
            if(albums.add(albumObject){
                rank++;
            } else{
                throw new DuplicateAlbumException("album: " + title + " exists");
            }
        } catch(InputMissmatchException exc){
            //print out an error about a bad line.
        } catch(DuplicateAlbumException exc){
            //print out an error about a duplicate album.
        }
    }
} catch(IOException e){
    //problem with the file 
}
```

One more thing, your Album class needs to override hashcode.

```
@Override
public int hashCode(){
    return title.hashCode() + artist.hashCode();
}
```